# Android v5.1.1 - Hybrid application crash with error Fatal:safe_conversionh.h(53) check failed

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch

I have developed a hybrid Android application by using Phonegap(3.6.3) and Sencha Touch(2.4.1).
The application runs perfectly fine on Android versions prior to 5.1.1.
But on 5.1.1 and later version the application just crashed with following error in logcat:

```
A/chromium(18332): [FATAL:safe_conversions.h(53)] Check failed: false. 
A/google-breakpad(18619): -----BEGIN BREAKPAD MICRODUMP-----
A/google-breakpad(18619): V WebView:46.0.2490.76
A/google-breakpad(18619): O A arm 04 armv7l Sony/D2403/D2403:5.1.1/18.6.A.0.175/1807889774:user/release-keys
A/google-breakpad(18619): S 0 BE838B10 BE838000 00007000
A/google-breakpad(18619): S BE838000
```